# CardLayout alignment is not proper

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, cardlayout

I am a beginner to java. In second cardpanel the username and password alignment is not coming properly. Is there any way to fix it? I would also like to know what is the disadvantage of using multiple frames.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class CardLayoutTest extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JPanel cardPanel, jp1, jp2, buttonPanel;
        private JLabel jl1, jl2;
        private JTextField jt1;
        private JPasswordField jt2;
        private JButton btn1, btn2;
        private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

        public CardLayoutTest() {
            setTitle("Login");
            setSize(400, 300);
            cardPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            cardPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
            jp1 = new JPanel();
            jp2 = new JPanel();
            jt1=new JTextField();
            jt2=new JPasswordField();
            jl1 = new JLabel("Username");
            jl2 = new JLabel("Password");
            //jp1.add(jl1);
            jp2.add(jl1);
            jp2.add(jt2);
            jp2.add(jl2);
            jp2.add(jt2);
            cardPanel.add(jp1, "1");
            cardPanel.add(jp2, "2");
            btn2 = new JButton("Show Card 2");
            btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "2");
                }
            });
            buttonPanel.add(btn2);
            add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CardLayoutTest frame = new CardLayoutTest();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In second cardpanel the username and password alignment is not coming properly.

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout so the components are displayed on a single line.

> Is there any way to fix it?

Use an appropriate layout manager (or combination of layout managers) to get the desired alignment.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.